# Visual studio - build selection not available

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 the option to build a single file, via the command "Build Selection" has suddenly become unavailable. I can however still build and as far as I know I did not change any solution/project properties.

What can I do to make this option available again?

Answer (score 0):

If you open a file and do not [add it to a project] then apparently MSVS doesn't know how to build it. Simply adding it to my project fixed this problem.